# How to optimize Metal pipeline

Tags: metal

I have a chain of shaders who pass `MTLTexture` to each other. Tho I'm getting bad performance. I know this is a very generic question.

I have an example that takes around 100ms to render, way to long for one frame. It's around 10 source textures at 1080p. Then a bunch of shader effect operations. Is there maybe a way to share the memory for the 10 textures?

Comment: What do you mean you have "shaders who pass MTLTexture to each other though the CPU". That makes no sense to me. Show code. Also, don't guess about performance; measure it.

Comment: If, for example, you're using something like the `getBytes` and `replaceRegion` methods to copy data between textures, there's almost certainly a more efficient way to do what you're achieving. But as Ken says, we don't yet know enough about your conversion to provide concrete advice.

Comment: @KenThomases I was just assuming MTLTextures where passed though the CPU, I might be wrong. Just trying to optimise the render pipeline...

Comment: Here's my render pipeline: https://github.com/hexagons/pixels/blob/feature/live/Source/PixelsRender.swift#L139

Comment: Here's how I pass the textures: https://github.com/hexagons/pixels/blob/feature/live/Source/PixelsTexture.swift#L192

Comment: I've updated the question.